# How can the ShieldUI ComboBox AutoComplete text be cleared after finding a match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, autocomplete, shieldui

ComboBox problem
- with AutoComplete
- type a few chars that are found in multiple strings
- select an item
- tab or click out of the Combo
- click the dropdown of the Combo
- only the items that match the chars you typed are shown

I want to clear the typed char buffer after losing focus so that you can select a different value when revisiting the Combo.
Does anyone know how to do this in ShieldUI?